# Geometric meaning of complex integration.

Tags: complex-analysis

What is geometric meaning of complex integration? I think there is no geometric meaning of complex integration as in Riemann's integration. Please describe it. Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904493/geometric-interpretation-of-complex-path-integral, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377910/geometrical-interpretation-of-a-line-integral-issue.