# Question on z-score

Tags: normal-distribution

I saw this somewhere. Is this right?

$ P(z< -4.3333)=0.00003 $

Most z-score table stops at 3.4. If this is right, kindly explain how it was gotten. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a ti84?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla No I don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

This $z$-score is calculated as $$P(z<-4.3333) = \int_{-\infty}^{4.333} f(z)\mathrm{d}z$$

where $f(z)$ is the pdf for the standard normal distribution.Every $z$-score is calculated in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although, I don't really comprehend. This looks advance. Can you explain more?

Comment: Sure! The $z$-score is nothing more than the area under the standard normal curve. The area under the curve is given by the integral, which is a calculus notion. If you can imagine approximating the area by rectangles, then do it again with smaller rectangles you can begin to understand the intuition of an integral. The tables in your book stop at 3.4 and -3.4 because at that point you will have about 99.99% of all data accounted for.

Comment: Check out this page for a nice intuitive explanation of integral http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916569/intuitive-explanation-for-integration

Comment: Thank you very much. I just need one more thing. Can you kindly expatiate on this using this particular question as an example so I can understand well.
P(z< -4.3333)=0.00003. Can you solve here to show how it was gotten

Comment: We can't. The integral cannot be evaluated by elementary methods. We can only approximate it using power series or other tools. Hence, why we have tables and computers to this.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I tried using Excel to get it. It displayed an error message. What software can I use to solve it then?

Comment: You likely typed it in wrong then. Try `=NORM.DIST(-4.3333, 0, 1, TRUE)`. Read the documentation or do a search for other tools online.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It was most likely obtained by the integral representation:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{t} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \ dz $$

Of course any computer can do this. Many tables stop at a score of 3 because it is less than anything practical.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this looks kinda advanced. How can I find it without using a computer

Comment: If you don't have a computer or a calculator capable of doing these calculations, then for all purposes, assume that for $z < -3.5$ we have $P(Z < z) = 0$. You can only use the limitations of your table.